# How can a user perform a "starts-with" search in a RadGrid?

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

As shown below, I have a column from my radgrid.

It holds a list of floors in a building.  If the user enters "5" in the search
grid, it returns floors 5 and 15.

Is there a search operator that can be used so that the user can search for 
the 5th floor without the records for the 15th floor being returned?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a filter row in your header by using this attribute in your RadGrid:

```
AllowFilteringByColumn="True"
```

Then you'll see a dropdown next to the textarea where you can select "StartsWith" or other comparison function.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `AllowFilteringByColumn="True"` in radgrid or in mastertableview.

set `CurrentFilterFunction="StartsWith"` in the columns, if you want to set the default filter function for a particular column